# How make NetRW always open the provided dir, even when there is already an upper dir opened?

Tags: netrw

I created a `Drawer` command to use NetRW as a file drawer with two main uses.

Note: I always use the *tree listing mode*.

1. Open the working directory
2. Find a file to allow viewing/opening its siblings

The commands are below:

```
" open netrw/Explore (similar to NERDTree)
command! -nargs=? Drawer if winnr("$") == 1 | Vexplore <args>| else | 1 wincmd w | Explore <args> | endif
command! DrawerCwd execute 'Drawer' getcwd()
command! DrawerFind let @/=expand("%:t") | execute 'Drawer' expand("%:p:h") | normal n
```

The only problem is that NetRW won't open a directory if there is already an upper directory open, and this makes my `DrawerFind` useles when I already have a NetRw window opened.

Here are some examples:

```
:Explore /foo/bar/baz  " opens /foo/bar/baz dir

:Explore /foo/bar      " move up to /foo/bar as expected

:Explore /foo/bar/baz  " won't move down to /foo/bar/baz until window is closed
```

---

How can make NetRW descend to lower directories when an upper one is already viewed?

Comment: I suppose you could netrw’s `cd` equivalent

Comment: Can you please elaborate? :/

Comment: typing cd in a netrw buffer will change vim’s current directory to the one currently being browsed. That said, I don’t have the issue you’re describing when I use `:e` with a directory—perhaps the explore command handles a bit different

Comment: Just found that it only happens whe using the tree listing style. Setting `let g:netrw_liststyle=3` or typing `i` until tree style is selected.